# Help with user onboarding UX

Tags: onboarding, user-journey, task-flow

Background : I am creating an app that caters to the new parents to track details about their kid's activities etc. As part of onboarding, I want to capture details about their kid, presently it is restricted to capture details of up to 2 kids max.

I am in bit of struggle, on identifying how best to optimize the flows for an overall UX.

Here is what the current flow looks like.

User(parents) log in, they are presented with a welcome screen > they click Next to start onboarding their kids > I present a radio button with 2 options - Single Child and 2 Children [New Screen]. Assuming the parents pick Single Child > New Screen with just a text field to capture childs name, followed by a Next button > New Screen with FormFields for Age, Weight and Date of Birth followed by Save button.

Now assuming the Parents choose the second option( 2 children) > New screen with 2 text fields to capture names of both the child, followed by Next button > New screen with form fields similar to the first flow, followed by a button "Save and Next" which clears the form fields to capture the details of the second child and ultimately the final Save button.

Here is the flow I captured on Draw.io.

[image]

Please suggest ways to optimize this flow.

Comment: You didn't ask, but letting the user track their first two children for free - and making the user pay to track additional children - feels like a model that isn't based on tracking *people*. It makes children seem like items. Good UX means pushing back on things like that.

Answer (score 2):

Why is it limited to only two profiles?

I think you can reduce the process to just one step if there is a single child or multiple steps if there is more than one.

- If there is only one child, the data is filled in, <kbd>save</kbd> and
  <kbd>next</kbd> (or <kbd>Close</kbd>)
- If there are more children <kbd>+</kbd>
- In case of fewer children <kbd>–</kbd>
- The <kbd>–</kbd> button in the first child returns to the
  home screen

[image]

#### Edit after the comment

If the free version only allows to interact with two children, the third click on <kbd>+</kbd> opens a toast alert saying something similar to:

> The free version only allows you to add two children, get the plus version to add more children.

Comment: The idea is, free version will let you add only 2 children at the max. At this time, the free version is kind of an MVP. What you showed is an interesting way. Would you think adding an instructional text which says "only 2 children allowed" or something like that. So that the user wont be clicking on the "+" button?

Answer (score 0):

I would separate each child so that you are only focused on one child at a time. If I enter both names on the same screen and then have to enter the first childs info, I might forget which child I entered first. I suggest two screens, one where you enter the first childs information, name and all. The second is where you focus on just the second child's information. That way there could be no confusion as to which child's info you are inputting

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the expectations upfront that you allow upto two child for the free version and allowing upgrade if they have more than 3 child to avoid after shock.

As rightly, pointed the problem with CHILD 1, Plus CHILD 2 Approach by Danielle there are chances they might forget which details they entered i.e Younger or Elder.

Note: You might give an option to Add addiotional child if a parents want to and in that case you need to pull in the upgrade version then.

[image]